# What is the probability distribution of a function of a uniform random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Suppose random variable $X$ has a uniform distribution: $X\sim U[-x_0, x_0]$.
>
> What is the probability distribution function (pdf) of $Y$ where
>
> \begin{equation}
> Y=
> \begin{cases}
> \cos^2\left(\frac{aX}{2}\right) & \hspace{4mm} \text{for} \hspace{4mm} |X|\leq \frac{\pi}{a}\\
> 0 & \hspace{4mm} \text{for} \hspace{4mm}  \frac{\pi}{a} < |X|<\pi\qquad?
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Here is the approach I followed to solve this problem:

1) Find the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of Y: $F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y)$

2) pdf function is the derivative of the cdf function $f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)$

(I am not sure about the rest)

If $|x_0|<\frac{\pi}{a}$  then,

$$ \cos^2\left(\frac{ax_0}{2}\right)\leq y \leq 1$$

\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=P(Y \leq y)
\\&= P\left\{\cos^2\left(\frac{aX}{2}\right)\leq y\right\}
\\&=P\left( \frac{2}{a} \arccos(\sqrt {y})\leq X \leq x_0\right)+P\left( -x_0\leq X \leq -\frac{2}{a} \arccos (\sqrt {y})\right)
\end{align}

So,

$$F_Y(y)=1-\frac{2}{ax_0}\arccos (\sqrt {y})$$

Therefore, the pdf function can be written as

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{ax_0\sqrt {y}\sqrt {1-y}},\hspace{2mm} \text{for}\hspace{2mm} \cos^2\left(\frac{ax_0}{2}\right)< y <1,$$

which I believe is not correct as it does not integrate to $1$ (WHY?).

If $|x_0|\geq \frac{\pi}{a} $  then, $ 0 \leq y \leq 1$

And I believe the CDF function can be obtained the same as above.

Comment: $Y$ has a discrete mass point at $0$, so it is not absolutely continuous (cannot have a density).

Comment: Since you asked pretty much the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889076/cdf-of-a-piecewise-continuous-non-monotonic-function-of-a-random-variable) some time back, you could have edited that post with this added context, and the post would have been reopened.

Comment: It was closed because it lacked the context you have added here by showing your work. There is an 'edit' button that allows you to update your posts. Not a big deal, just letting you know for the future.

Comment: There is a gap in the definition of $Y$, since you did not specify the relationship between $\pi$ used in the definition of $Y$ and $x_0$ used to define the distribution of $X$.

Comment: $x_0$ is not specified, in face : $0<x_0<\pi$. That's why I tried to solve the problem form different values of $x_0$ meaning $x_0<\pi/a$ and  $x_0 \geq \pi/a$ for each of which $y$ has values over different ranges.

Comment: How does $Y$ have gap? it's value is $0$ at $X=\frac{\pi}{a}$ and stays zero from there to $\pi$.